# Magento SOAP API - PHP Exception thrown for login method call: "looks like we got no XML document"

Tags: php, magento, soap, wsdl

I'm having issues connecting to the Magento SOAP API via PHP's SoapClient. I have a small test PHP file setup on my dev server with the following code:

```
<?php
$soapC = new SoapClient('http://XXXX.com/api/soap/?wsdl', array('trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>false));
$session = $soapC->__soapCall('login', array('TestUsr', 'test123'));
var_dump($session);
?>
```

The PHP file is on the same server as my magento dev build. When I run the php script via the command line, the $session variable outputs a SoapFault object with an error that says "looks like we got no XML document".

Not sure how to resolve this. When I try the code below I'm able to get a print out of all of the API methods, but for some reason the login method call above is causing problems.

```
$soapC = new SoapClient('http://XXXX.com/api/soap/?wsdl', array('trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>false));
print_r($soapC->__getFunctions());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the issue was that when the server tried to access the wsdl file, Magento was issuing a 302 redirect to the storefront.

To fix it, I logged into the Magento admin panel, navigated to System -> Configuration -> Web, and turned off "Auto-redirect to Base URL". Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 3):

This error generally means the problem is on the server side. The server handling the request is not outputting valid XML. Check that there are no errors or redirects occurring.

What happens if you visit the server end-point in a browser?

Comment: Yeah, the wsdl file loads in the browser just fine, and I'm not seeing any errors appear in the error log.

Comment: Your WSDL should have something similar to this; `<soap:address location="http://example.com/server.php?v=1.0"/>`. This is the URL you need to visit. If there are still no issues, could post a link to your WSDL?

Comment: Thanks for your assistance on this. Turns out there was a 302 redirect that prevented the wsdl from ever being reached.

Answer (score 0):

Open your **php.ini** file from your remote server or local server and set **always_populate_raw_post_data** to **-1**.

After that you need to restart your Apache server.

Once restart have done please run your script again.