# Magento 1.9.1.0 : Unable to load WSDL using soap cleint

Tags: php, web-services, magento, soap, wsdl

I have tried all the answers given in the following threads.

[1] [Magento SOAP API - PHP Exception thrown for login method call: "looks like we got no XML document"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906775/magento-soap-api-php-exception-thrown-for-login-method-call-looks-like-we-go)

[2] [Magento SOAP API - PHP Exception error “looks like we got no XML document”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273019/magento-soap-api-php-exception-error-looks-like-we-got-no-xml-document)

I am able to load the WSDL in the browser and the WSDL URL is in this format

http://www.foo.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl

This is the error am getting in the console:

`looks like we got no XML document` .

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually related to Magento setting up a `SoapServer`, and not to your `SoapClient` call, which in turn means that it's usually a problem of your **server** not being able to fetch the WSDL.  Connect toyour server via `ssh` and issue the following command (with your URL)

```
$ curl -i 'http://www.foo.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'
```

This will output the HTTP headers, and the response.  My guess is the response isn't valid XML (includes debugging, or whitespace), `curl` couldn't connect to the server (because your host's networking is wrong) or your WSDL points to other WSDLs that can't be connected to.

Solve that problem, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: I have validated the xml . It is fine.

Comment: @praveenreddydandu No you haven't.  You've validated the XML you're seeing from the client, or some other XML you're seeing somewhere, but you haven't validated the XML that Magento `SoapServer` itself sees, or else you wouldn't be getting that error.

Comment: HTTP headers :` HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 21 Aug 2015 18:17:33 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache`